# WP_Query with posts sorted by comments date

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Same as title: I need make Wordpress loop that will display posts sorted by comments date.
Like on forum, first is post with the latest comment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you already tried? Did you run into any problems with your own code?

Comment: I have seen in wordpress codex that there are no sorting comments date parameters and only after the date of post.
I tried something like: $args = array(
 'cat'         => $category,
 $comments = get_comments( array(
     'post_id' => $post->ID,
     'status' => 'approve'
   ) ),
 'orderby' => $comments[0]->comment_date
);                                                                                                                                        Not working

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting. There might be two approached which can resolve this.
**1 -**

```
$args = array(
    'status' => 'approve',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

$comments = get_comments( $args );
$ids = array();

foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {

     $post = get_post( $comment->comment_post_ID );

     if(!in_array($post->ID, $ids):
        $ids[] = $post->ID;
        echo $post->title;
     endif;

}
```

**2 -**
Add a action to add a meta to the post for the recent comment date.

```
add_action('comment_unapproved_to_approved', 'wpc_2511_comment_approved');
function wpc_2511_comment_approved($comment) {
    $comment_post_ID = $comment->comment_post_ID;
    $date = $comment->comment_date;
    update_post_meta( $comment_post_ID, '_recent_comment_date', $date );
```

}

Then write the query string to get the posts sorted by meta_key & meta_value Descending
Like:

```
$args = array(
  'post_status'       => 'publish',
  'post_type'         => 'post'
  'meta_key'          => '_recent_comment_date',
  'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
  'order'             => 'DESC'
);
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Hmm.. I would like display this loop with posts on category page. 
Sorry, your code not working.. If I comment this line: 'meta_key'          => '_recent_comment_date', the loop displays posts but not in the correct order

Comment: Ok.  
I noticed only when adding a new comment in database added meta_key '_recent_comment_date'. 
I need to add this to existing posts as well ...